# Consecutive use of kmap_atomic() and kunmap_atomic()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a loadable module for Linux kernel, where I have a need to map and unmap memory pages. It happens while all interrupts are disabled. The sequence of actions looks like this:

```
preempt_disable();
disable_all_interrupts(&interrupt_mask_saved);
kmap_atomic(page); // here i map ONE page
do_some_work();
kunmap_atomic(page); // unmapping ONE page
restore_all_interrupts(interrupt_mask_saved);
preempt_enable();
```

With actions like these it all works pretty well. But when I need to map/unmap several pages (i need it to improve cpu load) like this:

```
preempt_disable();
disable_all_interrupts(&interrupt_mask_saved);
for (i = 0; i < page_num; i++) {
  kmap_atomic(page[ i ]); // here i map several pages
}
do_some_work();
// i tried backward unmapping but the result is the same
for (i = 0; i < page_num; i++) { 
  kunmap_atomic(); // unmapping several pages
}
restore_all_interrupts(interrupt_mask_saved);
preempt_enable();
```

The system crashes. Error and info messages are shown directly in the terminal when not in graphic mode. After outputting some messages to the screen system freezes. Kernel logs are empty, but the errors which I noticed are:

```
scheduling while atomic
thread overran stack or stack corrupted
```

In Linux code I found than kunmap_atomic use preempt_schedule() and probably this is the cause of scheduling while atomic. But I rewrote my own functions of kmap_atomic and kunmap_atomic without dealing with preemptions and it still doesn't work. Actions which I do between mapping and unmapping are not the cause because I tried without them and it still freezes.

Linux kernel version: 3.0.48, Distr AltLinux 7.0.1 and Altlinux 6.0
Kernel version 3.4.62 works fine but I need exactly 3.0.48

I've been struggling with it for a while but I have no ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: Please don't keep the error messages secret. How many pages are you trying to map? Why do you think you can unmap the pages in any order except backwards?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pair nested kmap/kunmap functions.

Like:

```
for (i = 0; i < page_num; i++) { 
    address[i] = kmap_atomic(page[i]);
}

do_some_work();

for (i = page_num - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    kunmap_atomic(address[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calling schedule or anything that sleeps when in interrupt context is the cause

even though u have removed preempt_schedule, there might be something still **sleeping** and sleeping calls schedule, Check this